# Devexpress GridView Merge Only non-empty cells

Tags: winforms, gridview, devexpress

In my gridview (devexpress) there are some empty cells and some non-empty. When I merge cells, both empty and non-empty cells are merged.

But I want to merge only cells which are not empty. I want empty cells appear as they normally are (unmerged)..
Thanks.

```
   private void gridView2_CellMerge(object sender, CellMergeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.FieldName == "Aktivite")
        {
            var value1 = gridView2.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle1, e.Column).ToString();
            var value2 = gridView2.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle2, e.Column).ToString();


            if (value1 == value2 && (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value1) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(value2)))
            {
                e.Merge = true;
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the else chain for your if.  Try to change the code as follows:

```
e.Merge = value1 == value2 && (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value1) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(value2));
e.Handled = true;
```

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

You handle the event when the cells are not empty. But you need to do the opposite. You need to handle the event when the cells are empty:

```
private void gridView2_CellMerge(object sender, CellMergeEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.FieldName == "Aktivite")
    {
        var value1 = gridView2.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle1, e.Column).ToString();
        var value2 = gridView2.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle2, e.Column).ToString();

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value1) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(value2))
        {
            e.Merge = false;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```